# Problem in Graphics with my new Ubuntu system

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, resolution

I am new to Ubuntu and have just bought a new laptop with Ubuntu 12.04. It has Nvidia 820M GPU. I installed the drivers ( ver 331) from Synaptic package manager and rebooted my system. Now my screen is with some very bad resolution and I am not able to correct it. I tried using this link

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

to correct the resolution  but no use (I tried using addmode and newmode with xrandr, but since I am new to ubuntu, I dont think I am able to properly understand how to do it).

As mentioned in some of the links, I also went to additional drivers. It shows there nvidia 331 and says " This driver is activated but not cuurently in use"

Right now, I am somehow working with that incorrect resolution. Some quick help to permanently solve the issue would be welcome.

GPU : NVIDIA geforce 820M

Driver version : 331 (just updated)

Desired resolution : 1366 x 768 at 60 Hz

Thanks

```
Update
```

I managed to create a new modeline . When running simply the command xrandr it shows following items :

```
Screen 0 : .........

eDP1 connected 640x480+0+0 ....

DP1 disconnected

HDMI1 diconnected
```

So I ran the command xrandr --addmode "eDP1" "1368x768_60.00" but it shows following errors

```
X Error of failed request              : BadMatch ( invalid parameter attributes)

Major opcode of failed request         :     140 (RANDR)

Minor " " "  "                         :     18 (RRAddOutputMode)

Serial Number "" ""                    :     30

Current Serial number in output stream :     31
```

(I already succesfully created new mode "1368x768_60.00" with cvt )

What to do ?

```
Update 2
```

Although I managed to solve the above problem as mentioned in comment below, there is a new problem now. The change is not permanent. I followed the link

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

and edited the xorg.conf file. The lines are even present everytime I restart. But the resolution is back to bad and i have to execute the xrandr everytime. Any help is welcome.

```
Update 3
```

Looks like I have destroyed my new laptop. It cant boot now. I think I edited the xorg.conf incorrectly ( I edited the file again after Edit 2). What now ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `gksudo nvidia-settings` to make your changes? You might also want to look at the [Binary Driver Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).

Comment: Well, after so many hours, I finally found what the problem was. While using cvt utility, it was generating the mode as 1368x768, although I was asking it to generate modeline for 1366x768 ( 2 pixels less). So I changed in the generated modeline 1368 to 1366, and it worked.